# convert my string to AM or PM hour in ActionScript 3

Tags: string, actionscript-3, time, format

I've got a `String` variable for my time :

```
    var $myTime:String;

    //Some calculation

    trace(myTime); 
// Result is : 14:25 (for example)
```

I'm looking for a way to convert this string ("`14:25`" in this example) to a simple AM / PM format.

So in this example it would be, for example, `2 PM`

Any idea how I can simply do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myTime:Date = new Date();
var timeString:String;

if (myTime.getHours() > 12)
{
    timeString = String((myTime.getHours() - 12) + ":" + myTime.getMinutes() + " PM");
}
if (myTime.getHours() == 12)
{
    timeString = String(myTime.getHours() + ":" + myTime.getMinutes() + " PM");
}
if (myTime.getHours() < 12)
{
    timeString = String(myTime.getHours() + ":" + myTime.getMinutes() + " AM");
}

trace(timeString);
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateFormatter` class to set your wished pattern.

You can write your code as follow:

```
var df:DateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
df.formatString = "YYYY-MM-DD L:NN:SS";

df.format(myTime);
```

Where L is `HOUR` with PM/AM; NN are the minutes SS seconds.

You can see the complete guide, about DateFormatter pattern, [**here**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/DateFormatter.html)